# How to print GNU Parallel command & output together?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'd like to just check the status of a bunch of Git repos with a quick command like `parallel git -C {} status --short ::: ~/*/.git/..`. But the Git status doesn't include the repo name or path, so I'd need some way to print either the `git` command run by `parallel` or (ideally) just the input (the `~/[…]/.git/..` part of the command) and then the output relevant to that repo. Is this possible? `--verbose` will print the command, but doesn't print the command output next to the command, so that's not good enough. And `--group` will keep lines from one job together, but doesn't keep those lines together with the command printed by `--verbose`, so those two are not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
parallel --tagstring {//} git -C {//} status --short ::: ~/*/.git
```

or:

```
parallel --plus --tagstring {=s:$HOME.::';s:/.git::'=} git -C {//} status --short ::: ~/*/.git
```

or:

```
parallel -v git -C {//} status --short ::: ~/*/.git
```

It is not exactly what you ask for, but may be an acceptable solution.

A solution matching your requirement would be:

```
parallel "echo {};git -C {} status --short" ::: ~/*/.git/..
```

Comment: [Fixed](https://gitlab.com/engmark/tilde/-/commit/3dc46e6245ee6677cdecd5f6370255e68048ccc0), woot!

Answer (score 1):

`parallel --group --jobs=1 --verbose […]` will print the command, then the command output, then move on to the next command. Disadvantages:

- It won't run any commands in parallel, so it's about as slow as a `for` loop.
- It prints the full command rather than just the input.
- `--verbose` prints the command on standard error, so I'd have to  `2>&1` to run the output through `less` or a filter.